# Convert snapshot data to historical data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently developing a data warehouse and migrating data from a source system that takes snapshot of the transaction database everyday regardless of changes or not. This table as you would expect has become very large (about 100 million rows) over the years and looks like this.

[image: Snapshot Table]

Desired Table should look like this

[image: DW Table]

Comment: Sample data as text (not an image) would be more helpful

Comment: Without sample data google Gaps-and-Islands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seem you need simply `group by` with aggregation :

```
select branchcode, productcode, min(fromsalesdate), max(tosalesdate), qtysold, amount
from table t
group by branchcode, productcode, qtysold, amount;
```

Comment: A simple group by won't do it.  It could generate overlaps.  This is more of a Gaps-and-Islands problem